# dividing numerator with non zero denominator always gives zero in c#

Tags: c#, linq

here is my code

```
DataTable dt=STP_GetRenewalResultsReportData(Convert.ToDateTime("06-07-2015"),Convert.ToDateTime("06-07-2016")).Tables[0];
(
from r in
(
from d in dt.AsEnumerable() 
group d by d.Field<string>("CityID") into grpCity
select new{
 CityID = grpCity.Key,
                      City = (from g in grpCity where g.Field<string>("CityID") == grpCity.Key select g.Field<string>("City")).First().Trim(),
                      PotentialRenewalCount = (from g in grpCity where g.Field<string>("CityID") == grpCity.Key select g.Field<int>("PotentialRenewalCount")).Sum(),
                      // PotentialRenewalCount = 205,
                      PotentialRenewalSQRT = (from g in grpCity where g.Field<string>("CityID") == grpCity.Key select g.Field<double>("PotentialRenewalSQFT")).Sum(),
                     RENEWALCOUNT = (from g in grpCity where g.Field<string>("CityID") == grpCity.Key select g.Field<int>("RENEWALCOUNT")).Sum(),
                      // RENEWALCOUNT = 23,
                     RENEWALSQRT = (from g in grpCity where g.Field<string>("CityID") == grpCity.Key select g.Field<double>("RENEWALSQRT")).Sum(),                   

}
)
select new{
CityID=r.CityID,
City=r.City,
PotentialRenewalCount=r.PotentialRenewalCount,
PotentialRenewalSQRT=r.PotentialRenewalSQRT,
RENEWALCOUNT=r.RENEWALCOUNT,
RENEWALSQRT=r.RENEWALSQRT,
LeaseNoPercentage=Convert.ToDouble(12/30)
}

).Dump();
```

now when you look at this line at the bottom

> LeaseNoPercentage=Convert.ToDouble(12/30)

i am dividing a very small number by 30 and as a result i am getting 0 when the exact result is 0.4

so my question is how can i get 0.4 in this LINQ instead of 0

thank you for your help

Comment: Why not use `12d/30d` (I have no clue if this works)

Comment: Even `Convert.ToDouble( (12/30) );` might yield a different result. But are you really doing 12/30 every time? Why not just have a constant value of 0.4 if that's what you need.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  If all you wanted to do was to divide 2 int literals and get a double, then you might as well just do `LeaseNoPercentage = 0.4`

Comment: yup! i am sorry, previously the title was very misleading. working late and was frustrated with the result everytime returning zero when the division of non zero numerator....thank you all for your help....it saved my time

Answer (score 1):

`12` and `30` are integers.

`12/30` does integer division, and results in `0`.

Converting `0` the int to a double results in `0` the double.

---

Since you said that your code is running, I'm going to assume that your call to `Convert.ToDouble` isn't throwing any sql-related exception, If that is the case, the following should work.

```
LeaseNoPercentage=Convert.ToDouble(12)/Convert.ToDouble(30)
```

That way, you'll do `double` division instead of integer division, and it should result in `0.4`

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Linq. Your expression

LeaseNoPercentage=Convert.ToDouble(12/30)

first evaluates 12/30. Both arguments are integers, so the result is 0.

That result is then passed to Convert.ToDouble(). Converting the integer 0 to a double yields 0.0.

To avoid the issue, you need to convert 12 and 30 to double before performing division. The most straightforward way is to write them as 12.0 and 30.0. If your real code has integer variables rather than constants (lets call them num and denom), you could do:

```
LeaseNoPercentage = (double)num / (double)denom;
```